# R ggplot bubble chart localised bubbles display without in single chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridview, bubble-chart

Hello R/ggplot experts!

R and ggplot learner here.

I was working on a scenerio and was thinking, how I can display the data in best possible way.
I need suggestion and direction from you guys.

**R reproducible ggplot**:

```
library(ggrepel)

# Create the data frame.
sales_data <- data.frame(
  emp_name <- c("Sam", "Dave", "John", "Harry", "Clark", "Kent", "Kenneth", "Richard", "Clement", "Toby"), 
  month <- as.factor(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan")),
  dept_name <- as.factor(c("Production", "Services", "Support", "Support", "Services", "Production", "Production", "Support", "Support", "Support")), 
  revenue <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200)
)

sales_data$month <- factor(sales_data$month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"))

categorical_bubble_chart <-  ggplot(sales_data, aes(x= month, y = dept_name, size = revenue, fill = revenue, label = revenue)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, show.legend = FALSE) 

categorical_bubble_chart
```

**Output plot is**:
[image]

So far good!
To represent the data in best possible way in present scenerio. Here is what it should look like.
[image]

I am having difficulty in understanding following points:

1. How I can show categories of month("Jan", "Feb", "Mar") in between grid lines. Similarly for Departments. So that I can make a grid like region for each of the combination.
2. Right now, all bubbles are overlapping on each other. I want to put bubbles in non-overlapping manner. For that I am thinking to add one more column in my data frame and randomly assign a value such that, it will be used to plot it inside the grid region. But I am finding it difficult to understand, when my x/y are already `month` and `dept_name` then what random value I can provide to make each bubble different from each other ?

I have been thinking on it's solution since last 5-6 hours but couldn't find solution.
Any direction or suggestion would be highly appreciated and learning for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the @Wietze314 approach, "quick & dirty" single-chart built:

```
ggplot(data = sales_data, aes(x = month, y = dept_name)) +
  geom_tile(data = expand.grid(sales_data$month, sales_data$dept_name), 
            aes(x = Var1, y = Var2), fill = NA, col = 'gray50', lty = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(size = revenue, col = revenue), 
             shape = 16, position = position_jitter(seed = 0), show.legend = F) +
  geom_text(aes(label = revenue), vjust = 1.6, position = position_jitter(seed = 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_blank(), 
    panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid = element_blank()
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @utubun,
Can I ask something, why this method is not scalable ?
Let's say if run this code with data with 500 data. R studio hangs.

Comment: @OmPrakashSao that's because of `expand.grid()` call, most probably. If my math is right, given 500 points, `expand.grid()` will produce a data frame with 250000 rows. So after that, when the `geom_tile()` enters the scene, it must create 250000 tiles, which is probably too much. As I said earlier, it's a *quick and dirty* solution. In case when number of points relatively large, better to adapt @Wietze solution, or, even better - create your own `stat_` and `geom_` [see e.g. here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this? I could not find the positioning of the bubbels for each facet in your data, so I took revenue.

```
require(ggplot2)
# Create the data frame.
sales_data <- data.frame(
  emp_name = c("Sam", "Dave", "John", "Harry", "Clark", "Kent", "Kenneth", "Richard", "Clement", "Toby"), 
  month = as.factor(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan")),
  dept_name = as.factor(c("Production", "Services", "Support", "Support", "Services", "Production", "Production", "Support", "Support", "Support")), 
  revenue = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200)
)

sales_data$month <- factor(sales_data$month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"))

categorical_bubble_chart <-  ggplot(sales_data, aes(x= revenue, y = revenue, size = revenue, fill = revenue, label = revenue)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(dept_name~month)

categorical_bubble_chart
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Sir, You are truly a `R enthsiast`
Thanks a lot !
I will further play with this to learn more!

Comment: So, what I understand is, we have 9 different charts here, is there no possible way to do in single chart ?

Comment: I think you can look into making the space between the facets zero, so it looks like one chart. You can do this with `theme()`. If you want to have one plot then you have to invent an artificial axis value, such as month + revenue and dep_name + revenue. But I think this will be harder and more complex than to stick with facets.

Comment: Yes, that is one way. But, if we plot this in polar coordinate using `coord_polar()` , it shows 9 different polar coordinate. 

PS: I have to finally show this plot in polar way.