# ggplot2 Bubble Chart panel

Tags: r, ggplot2, panel, bubble-chart

I am working on trying to plot a bubble chart with multiple data variables on the same chart. I will try my best to describe what I would like the final output to appear and attempts from reading online and some questions posted on the forum.

I am just getting familiar with ggplot but if there is solution with another package, I am open to it.

C1 within circles represents color 1, C2 within squares represents color 2, C3 within triangles represents color 3.

I would think these will be 8 independent panels since the y-axis is different for each one.

Really appreciate the help.

The final outputs I would prefer is bubbles that have different size and color.  I think individual panels of 8 x 3 would be ideal because the y axis for each panel can be changed. But I cannot figure out how to structure the data to allow for creating 8 x 3 panels with individual y axes and the symbol size. Thanks Closest I came across: [R ggplot bubble chart localised bubbles display without in single chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55216948/r-ggplot-bubble-chart-localised-bubbles-display-without-in-single-chart)

Preferred output:

[image]

```r
library (tidyverse)
library (reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

data.tb <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 
3L, 12L, 13L, 4L, 14L, 5L, 15L, 6L), .Label = c("avg_row3", "avg_row4", 
"avg_row5", "avg_row6_7", "avg_row8", "avg_row9", "row1", "row2", 
"row3", "row4", "row5", "row6", "row7", "row8", "row9"), class = "factor"), 
    col1 = c(6333, 8847, 1495292, 169, 28994.1, 3.3, 12857.6, 
    1.5, 107154, 230344, 38.15, 837364, 132.8, 1226140, 176.74
    ), col2 = c(20347, 40594, 6229886, 153.5, 122769.8, 3, 44653.4, 
    1.1, 362972, 944725, 32.21, 3488736, 118.16, 5108506, 158.06
    ), total_col1_2 = c(23301, 49441, 7725178, 156.3, 151763.9, 
    3.1, 57511, 1.2, 470126, 1175069, 33.28, 4326100, 120.78, 
    6334646, 161.4), col3 = c(3313, 4668, 751824.1, 161.1, 14689.2, 
    3.2, 6784.2, 1.5, 107154, 230344, 72.3, 421021, 162.49, 616496, 
    204.37), col4 = c(10220, 20940, 3053539.5, 145.8, 60675.8, 
    2.9, 23034, 1.1, 362972, 944725, 62.45, 1709982, 144.11, 
    2503902, 182.02), total_col3_4 = c(13533, 25608, 3805363.6, 
    148.6, 75365, 2.9, 29818.2, 1.2, 470126, 1175069, 64.25, 
    2131004, 147.46, 3120398, 186.1), col5 = c(3020, 4179, 743468.1, 
    177.9, 14304.9, 3.4, 6073.5, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 416342, 99.63, 
    609644, 145.88), col6 = c(10127, 19654, 3176346.3, 161.6, 
    62094, 3.2, 21619.4, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 1778754, 90.5, 2604604, 
    132.52), total_col5_6 = c(13147, 23833, 3919814, 164.5, 76398.9, 
    3.2, 27692.9, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 2195096, 92.1, 3214248, 134.87
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

data_long.tb <- melt (data.tb, id.vars = c("Name"))

data_long.tb <- data_long.tb %>% mutate(group_num = 
                                          case_when(
                                            variable %in% c("col1", "col2", "total_col1_2") ~ "group1",
                                            variable %in% c("col3", "col4", "total_col3_4") ~ "group2",
                                            variable %in% c("col5", "col6", "total_col5_6") ~ "group3",
                                          ))
```

My attempts:

```
theme_set(theme_bw())  # pre-set the bw theme.
ggplot(data_long.tb,
       aes(variable, value)) + 
  geom_jitter (aes(col=variable, size=value))
```

[image]

```
theme_set(theme_bw())  # pre-set the bw theme.
ggplot(data_long.tb,
       aes(variable, value)) + 
  geom_jitter (aes(col=variable, size=value)) + facet_wrap(~ group_num)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please make the question reproducible by editing your question to include the output of running `dput(data.tb)` in the body of your question? This will create code that will allow us to create a perfect copy of `data.tb` without doing a bunch of manual wrangling.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I updated the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is quite it but hopefully closer.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Name) %>%  # reshape longer for ggplot
  mutate(Name = Name %>% fct_inorder %>% fct_rev) %>% # define order of Name, 
                                            # reversed so first is at bottom.

  group_by(Name) %>%               # within each Name...
  mutate(x_pos = row_number(),     # x_pos counts up in order...
         shape = case_when(name %in% c("col1", "col2", "total_col1_2") ~ "circle",
                           name %in% c("col3", "col4", "total_col3_4") ~ "square",
                           TRUE ~ "triangle")) %>% # and name determines shape
  ungroup() %>%

  ggplot(aes(x_pos, Name, size = value, shape = shape, color = shape)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_area() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("circle" = "red", "square" = "forestgreen", 
                                "triangle" = "purple")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("circle" = 19, "square" = 15, "triangle" = 17)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

##### Sample data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("row1", "row2", "row3", "avg_row3", "row4", 
"avg_row4", "row5", "avg_row5", "row6", "row7", "avg_row6_7", 
"row8", "avg_row8", "row9", "avg_row9"), col1 = c(6333, 8847, 
1495292, 169, 28994.1, 3.3, 12857.6, 1.5, 107154, 230344, 38.15, 
837364, 132.8, 1226140, 176.74), col2 = c(20347, 40594, 6229886, 
153.5, 122769.8, 3, 44653.4, 1.1, 362972, 944725, 32.21, 3488736, 
118.16, 5108506, 158.06), total_col1_2 = c(23301, 49441, 7725178, 
156.3, 151763.9, 3.1, 57511, 1.2, 470126, 1175069, 33.28, 4326100, 
120.78, 6334646, 161.4), col3 = c(3313, 4668, 751824.1, 161.1, 
14689.2, 3.2, 6784.2, 1.5, 107154, 230344, 72.3, 421021, 162.49, 
616496, 204.37), col4 = c(10220, 20940, 3053539.5, 145.8, 60675.8, 
2.9, 23034, 1.1, 362972, 944725, 62.45, 1709982, 144.11, 2503902, 
182.02), total_col3_4 = c(13533, 25608, 3805363.6, 148.6, 75365, 
2.9, 29818.2, 1.2, 470126, 1175069, 64.25, 2131004, 147.46, 3120398, 
186.1), col5 = c(3020, 4179, 743468.1, 177.9, 14304.9, 3.4, 6073.5, 
1.5, 0, 0, 0, 416342, 99.63, 609644, 145.88), col6 = c(10127, 
19654, 3176346.3, 161.6, 62094, 3.2, 21619.4, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 1778754, 
90.5, 2604604, 132.52), total_col5_6 = c(13147, 23833, 3919814, 
164.5, 76398.9, 3.2, 27692.9, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 2195096, 92.1, 3214248, 
134.87)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Only the values of Row1, avg_row3, avg_row4, avg_row5, avg_row6_7 with circle size being Row6, avg_row6_7 with circle size being Row7, Avg_row8 and Avg_row9 are to be plotted. I think individual panels of 8 x 3 would be ideal because the y axis for each panel can be changed. But I cannot figure out how to structure the data to allow for creating 8 x 3 panels with individual y axes and the symbol size. 

Thanks

Closest I came across: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55216948/r-ggplot-bubble-chart-localised-bubbles-display-without-in-single-chart